# How to copy frame data from FFmpegSource2 (FFMS2) FFMS_Frame struct to OpenCV Mat?

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, frame, mat

I'm trying to read video file using FFmpegSource2 (FFMS2) and then process frames using OpenCV. What is the proper and efficient way to copy frame data from a FFMS_Frame struct returned by FFMS_GetFrame function to an OpenCV Mat?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For now I am using the following procedure which works for the BGR color format.

Step 1. I use FFMS_SetOutputFormatV2 and FFMS_GetPixFmt( "bgra" ) to set output pixel format of FFMS to BGR.

```
int anPixFmts[2];
anPixFmts[0] = FFMS_GetPixFmt( "bgra" );
anPixFmts[1] = -1;

if( FFMS_SetOutputFormatV2( pstFfmsVidSrc, anPixFmts
    , pstFfmsFrameProps->EncodedWidth, pstFfmsFrameProps->EncodedHeight
    , FFMS_RESIZER_BICUBIC, &stFfmsErrInfo ) )
{
    // handle error
}
```

Step 2. Read the desired frame using FFMS_GetFrame.

```
int nCurFrameNum = 5;
const FFMS_Frame *pstCurFfmsFrame = FFMS_GetFrame( pstFfmsVidSrc, nCurFrameNum, &stFfmsErrInfo );
```

Step 3. Copy data from pstCurFfmsFrame to OpenCV Mat, oMatA:

```
Mat oMatA;
oMatA = Mat::zeros( pstCurFfmsFrame->EncodedHeight, pstCurFfmsFrame->EncodedWidth, CV_8UC3 );
int nDi = 0;
for( int nRi = 0; nRi < oMatA.rows; nRi++ )
{
    for( int nCi = 0; nCi < oMatA.cols; nCi++ )
    {
       oMatA.data[oMatA.step[0] * nRi + oMatA.step[1] * nCi + 0] = pstCurFfmsFrame->Data[0][nDi++]; // B
       oMatA.data[oMatA.step[0] * nRi + oMatA.step[1] * nCi + 1] = pstCurFfmsFrame->Data[0][nDi++]; // G
       oMatA.data[oMatA.step[0] * nRi + oMatA.step[1] * nCi + 2] = pstCurFfmsFrame->Data[0][nDi++]; // R
       nDi++;
    }
}
```

This code has to be changed to support other color formats (e.g Planar format like YV12 uses more than one plane of pstCurFfmsFrame->Data). May be someone could provide a full function to support most of the color formats and an efficient way to copy data from pstCurFfmsFrame->Data to OpenCV Mat.